# Smoothing artefacts

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, smoothing

By applying smoothing methods to physiological data, there will be sharp changes at the very beginning and very end of the signal, that could be smoothing artefacts, like at the beginning of the attached plot. What is the practice of avoiding them or compensating for them?

Plot:
[image: Plot]

The function I used for smoothing the curve:

```py
def MySmooth(X, Bin):
    X = np.hstack((X[0] * np.ones(Bin), X, X[-1] * np.ones(Bin)))
    X = np.convolve(X, np.ones(Bin) / Bin, mode='same')

    X = np.delete(X, np.arange(Bin))
    X = np.delete(X, np.arange(X.shape[0] - Bin, X.shape[0]))
    return X
```